# Automatically label newsletters in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I used filters to automatically label newsletters in Gmail. For example, I added a filter that matches incoming email id to `newsletter@brainpickings.org` etc. and labels them as `READING`. But for some reason, labels are not being automatically added as new emails arrive.

[image: READING filter]

How to debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step in debugging is to try with only one From: address. Does that work?

You need to break up the various From: addresses separated by **OR** operators. No email is going to be from `newsletter@brainpickings.org` *and* `NewYorker@newsletter.newyorker.com` *and* ... etc.

You want to change your filter to:

> Matches: from:(newsletter@brainpickings.org OR NewYorker@newsletter.newyorker.com OR team@email.digg.com OR harpers-weekly@harpers.org OR newsletters@fastcompany.com OR nytdirect@nytimes.com)

(Note that the "**OR**"s need to be in all uppercase for it to work properly.)